# How to run 'emacs' in the terminal emulator without a separate window?

Tags: linux, emacs

I am looking to switch to Emacs from Vim and one thing that is keeping me away is that Emacs opens up a separate window of its own when run under X. Can I get the same behavior for Emacs as Vim does when not run under X?

That is, I want Emacs to start the session in the same terminal as the one in which its fired.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm no emacs expert, but this did the trick for me:

```
emacs -nw
```

Comment: You're right, for the curious -nw is short for --no-window-system which tells emacs not to use its X interface.

Comment: @Mic: Thanks for the explanation, this way I'll remember what it stands for

Comment: Also, package **emacs-nox**, present in all common distributions, when installed instead of default **emacs-gtk**, contains Emacs build without X11 support.

Answer (score 17):

You might prefer starting emacs as `emacs --daemon` and then using `emacsclient -t` to edit files.  This keeps Emacs loaded in the background, so that you can use Emacs more like vi.  Editing sessions will start up instantly, and "quitting" via C-x C-c will just close the current connection.  It is very nice.

Answer (score 5):

Although your question has been answered, I would venture to say that this is not the way any regular user would use emacs. Unlike vim, emacs generally has a longer startup time and anyway tends to be running all the time with multiple open buffers. So when you want to do something with emacs in a terminal, you invoke `emacsclient -nw` (assuming an emacs serverhas been started). Look at [How to start to use EmacsClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient#toc1) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the above answers by Dick Kenny and Alberto Zaccagni you get the following configuration which I use in `.bashrc`:

```
alias emacs='emacsclient -nw -c -a ""'
```

This will try to connect to a runnning emacs daemon. If none is running, it will startup a new one, and then connect using the current terminal window.

From the docs:

```
-a EDITOR, --alternate-editor=EDITOR
        Editor to fallback to if the server is not running
        If EDITOR is the empty string, start Emacs in daemon
        mode and try connecting again

-nw, -t, --tty      Open a new Emacs frame on the current terminal

-c, --create-frame  Create a new frame instead of trying to 
                    use the current Emacs frame
```

Comment: When I try this command, Emacs fails to start, instead giving me a warning about there not being a server to connect to, followed by a giant dump of values and Emacs not starting.

Answer (score 2):

If you use bash, you can always add the following to your .bashrc

alias emacs="emacs -nw"

That's saved me a lot of typing (and cursing when I forget to type the switches).